# Get Row ID that has most recent date between two different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL Masters...  I'm trying to take a table of messages and get the single row with the maximum date when two rows "tie" due to their "type".  Here's the maximum values of each type (that must be in turn compared) from the table I'm pulling from:

```
id          type          typeId           createDate
234         S             344              4/5/2014
355         W             654              5/17/2014
```

The problem arises as the "types" of "S" and "W" are related to each other (the id field is not in the result I have as you can't group by id when it's the identity).  The table has MULTIPLE "types" that are related to each other.  For example, "type" "W" has a MANY to ONE relationship to "type" "S"... therefore, in this table, "W" may be related to "S" and it may not - there is a second table that makes this link (call this the "W" table):

```
id          s_type_id
654         234
```

Ok, so here's what I'm trying to do... I need to get the maximum value of the first table (messages) between the different types (the messages table is simplified above to show that I've been able to get the max messages of type "S" and the max messages of type "W", but can't seem to figure out how to get the max between both S & W (which should be the W value with the 5/17/2014 date) AND get the ID of that message (which should be 355).  Here is my expected result (which I will then use to back-join against the messages table to get the rest of the info in that table) - obviously not the correct query:

```
SELECT
    id,
    MAX(createdDate)
FROM
    messages


id          createdDate
355         5/17/2014
```

Back-joining is not working because the types are grouped by type (which excludes the id - which I am trying to get with your help).  Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: will `select top 1 id, createdDate from messages order by createdDate desc` work for you?

Comment: Alternatively you could use a simple subselect, e.g. `select id, createDate from test where createDate = ( select max(createDate) from test )`

Comment: Here's my concern about using createDate as the primary key... isn't it possible that more than one record has the same createDate value?  If so, that wouldn't help.  Also, SELECT TOP 1 id may work in this case, but none other that I can think of.

Comment: By the way, I have tried using createdDate as the primary key now and yes, it does bring back more than one record (as well as unrelated).  Using createdDate as the primary key will not work in this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.id, m.type, m.typeId, m.createDate
FROM
(
SELECT m.id, m.type, m.typeId, m.createDate, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
-- you can also keep one row per "group"
-- PARTITION BY m.type
ORDER BY m.createDate DESC
-- you can also specify a secondary ordering criteria
-- , m.type
) AS RowNum
FROM
messages m
) m
WHERE
m.RowNum = 1;
```